# How can we covert the string to date time and store it in varchar

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am using `varchar[1000]` in mysql database. I want to store the date time in that column. Then i need to convert it to `datatime` and store it in `varchar`. Can we convert and store in `varchar`.

Sorry if there are any mistakes. Any help is appreciated

Comment: why do you want to store a `datetime` as a `varchar`?  That is why there is a `datetime` datatype.

Comment: lets just clear it out, if you want to save it in a datetime column, just send it in that format
and if you want to save it as a varchar, it wont matter, in any format you send it

Comment: @bluefeet I will be having single column to save integer, string and datetime

Comment: 1000 characters seems a bit wide for a date time, no?

Comment: @Pa1 That is critical information that you should have included in your original post.

Comment: @Deepanshu it will be better to convert it to datetime and save it. So that next time when we loading there will be no errors.

Comment: @Pa1: You can call `.ToString()` on anything and store that result as a string.  To be clear, you're _not_ storing "integer, string and date time" in a `varchar` column.  You're _only_ storing strings there.  If you want to store integers and datetimes, you should store them in the correct formats.

Comment: @David i am not only using it for datetime. for other fields also

Comment: @Pa1: Why not break those other fields into their own... fields?

Comment: My requirement is different. It will be confusing if we break those

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you're *not* storing `DateTime` values in a `varchar` column.  You're storing string values.  Those string values might contain numeric characters or specific sequences of characters which a person may interpret as something specific (such as a date and/or a time), but they're still just strings.

So, in order to turn a value into a string, you start with [the `.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx).  For primitive types (such as integers and datetime values), this will return a string representation of that type.  For complex types, it'll return the name of the class so you'll need to override it in that class.

You can further refine your string representation of date and time values by using [custom string formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As others in the comments mention, you really should rethink your approach here. However, a `varchar` expects a string, not a datetime, so just save the `string` representation of your `datetime` value, no conversion necessary.

Answer (score 0):

do a varchar(10) maybe 
and then in your C# code:

```
date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

you can format your date like that.

Comment: Sounds like OP already has the string representation, not the `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

`varchar(1000)` makes no sense.  If you're storing date and time as a string, you don't need more than 15-20 characters (and possibly less, depending on the date format).

You should use the `CAST` operator to cast a `datetime` value to a string:

```sql
CAST(dt AS varchar)
```

If you need to generate output that combines data from several fields, you might want to use a view that combines the values you want to put together instead of dedicating a 1000-character field in a data table.  (Hint: Use the `concat()` function to concatenate multiple strings.)

Comment: I am not only storing `datetime`. Based on the requirement it may be `integer` or may `text` of `1000` characters. That's why it is dedicated with `varchar(1000)`

Comment: See my note on using a view for this purpose.